# Singularity of solution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions

We consider the equation $$\Delta u-q(x)u=0$$ in the circle 2D $B=\{|x| \leq 1\}$ with the boundary condition $u=1: \ |x|=1$, and the function $q$ is 
$$
q(x)=
\begin{cases}
\omega: \ |x| < \epsilon,\\
0: \ |x| \geq \epsilon
\end{cases}
$$
where $\omega$ and $\epsilon$ are positive constants.
In the case of radially symetric solution, the solution of this problem is:
$$
u(r)=
\begin{cases}
v(r)= C \left(1+ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{(\sqrt{\omega} r)^{2n}}{\Pi_{i=1}^n (2i)^2}\right) &: r < \epsilon\\
w(r)= \dfrac{a-1}{\ln \epsilon} \ln r+1 &:r > \epsilon
\end{cases}
$$
where $a= \dfrac{\gamma}{\gamma -1}$ whith $
\gamma = \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon \ln \varepsilon}  
\dfrac{1+ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \dfrac{ (\sqrt{\omega}\varepsilon)^{2n}}{\Pi_{i=1}^n (2i)^2}}
{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2n \dfrac{ (\sqrt{\omega} \varepsilon)^{2n-1}}{\Pi_{i=1}^n (2i)^2}   }
$

My question is: what's the singularities of the solution $u$ when $\omega \epsilon^2=1$? 
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Why do you expect a singularity in the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{4^n(n!)^2}$?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your comment. Can you help me please

Comment: You seem to expect that some singularity happens in this series for $x=ωϵ^2$, the question is where does that expectation come from as this is an entire function which is real positive on the positive real half-axis.

Comment: No, the singularity is when $\omega \epsilon^2=1$ not when $r= \omega \epsilon^2$. There is an logarithmic singularity when $\omega \epsilon^2=1$?

Comment: S there is no logarithmic singularity in this solution?

Comment: and if $r \in [(k+05)\epsilon, (l+0.5)\epsilon]$ we have singularities?

Comment: Sorry, should have written $ x=ωϵ^2=1$ in the formula of my first comment. You are aware that $\prod_{i=1}^n(2i)^2=4^n(n!)^2$? And what are $k$ and $l$ in relation to the problem or the solution formulas?