# Logarithmic Singularity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

What we means by " logarithmic singularity" of the solution $u$ of the equation $$\Delta u -q(x)u=0$$ where $q$ is defined by
$$
q(x)=
\begin{cases}
w &: x \in B(0,1)\\
0 &: x \notin B(0,1)
\end{cases}
$$
 Please

Comment: Please add information on the situation framing the question. In itself there is no reason for anything singular to occur. I assume this is related to your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2333455/singularity-of-solution and that perhaps to the convergence of the diverse solutions for $ε\to 0$ while $ωε^2=1$ which could be seen as an approximation of the not very well defined problem $Δu=c\delta_0u$ ($c=4\pi$?).

Comment: Please, we can write $\Delta u= \sum_{i,j} \delta_{x-x_{ij}}$ where $x_{ij}$ is numbers with entiers coordonnies $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0) ..$. In this case, the solution of the equation have the same comportement of the function $\log r$ when $\epsilon$ is fixed, and $\epsilon \leq r \leq 1$?